# Indy IdHTTP not reporting status correctly

Tags: http, indy, c++builder-xe7

I have assigned the `OnStatus` handler to update a label with the `AStatusText` parameter.

When setting a breakpoint in the handler it only breaks on the `hsConnected` status when I do a `Get("google.com")`. I know that I shouldn't get the full range but I should at least get the `hsResolving` and `hsConnecting` messages before the `hsConnected`.

List of available statuses:

```
hsResolving,
hsConnecting,
hsConnected,
hsDisconnecting,
hsDisconnected,
hsStatusText,
ftpTransfer,
ftpReady,
ftpAborted
```

Any idea of why I don't get the other statuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hsConnected` is reported by the `OnStatus` event of `TIdTCPClientCustom`, but the other statuses you are looking for are reported by the `OnStatus` event of `TIdIOHandler` instead.

If `TIdTCPClientCustom.Connect()` or `TIdCustomHTTP.CheckAndConnect()` has to create a new implicit IOHandler object, an `OnStatus` handler gets assigned to it so the `TIdTCPClientCustom.OnStatus` event is called.  However, if an IOHandler is already assigned before `Connect()` is called, no `OnStatus` handler gets assigned.  You would have to assign your own `OnStatus` handler to whatever IOHandler you assign.

*There is a TODO item to make the `OnStatus` event hookup more automated.*

The most likely scenario for this happening is if you are manually assigning your own SSLIOHandler before requesting HTTPS urls.  In that case, you can assign an `OnStatus` handler to your SSLIOHandler. On the other hand, if you are using an up-to-date version of Indy, it is able to create an implicit SSLIOHandler automatically (which includes `OnStatus` hookup) so you do not have to assign your own anymore (unless you need to customize its settings):

[New HTTPS functionality for TIdHTTP](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/blogs/ChangeLog/20141222.aspx)

> TIdHTTP now has new functionality that allows it to auto-create an internal default SSLIOHandler object when requesting an HTTPS url if no IOHandler has been assigned yet.

Comment: Thank you Remy I will try this as soon I can compile again. I'm having the LME288 problem right now...

Comment: Yes, I attached the same event handler to the IOHandler's OnStatus and now I get all the expected calls. Thank you.